# TSQL Extract Number Range from String with Known Ending

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract a number from a string of text. The number does not always occur in the same spot, but it will always end with a U.

Example:

```
Products  
----------------------------------------------
PRODUCT/100U/PRODUCT/1000A/10000E  
PRODUCT/100000A/PRODUCT/10U
PRODUCT/ITEM/1000U/PRODUCT/100000000E
```

I'd like to return 100, 10, and 1000 for the rows above. I've tried using `SUBSTRING` with `PATINDEX` and the `%[0-9]u%` wildcard, but the number value is not always a single digit.

Another solution I had come up with before @dfundako posted his and then using his logic for the `SUBSTRING` length.  It returns the same result as his, but with the U and all characters after that removed. Thank you for your help!

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@PRODUCT,PATINDEX('%/[0-9]%u%',@PRODUCT)+1,CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@PRODUCT])) +2),0,CHARINDEX('u',SUBSTRING(@PRODUCT,PATINDEX('%/[0-9]%u%',@PRODUCT)+1,CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@PRODUCT])) +2),0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks bad, but it works. First reverse the string, find '/U' (if it is not there because the U value is at the end, it should still work), find the next '/', take those two positions, pull the substring between them, and reverse the value.  If there are multiple U values per string, this won't work. You would need to loop it.

```
DECLARE @test1 VARCHAR(100) = 'PRODUCT/100U/PRODUCT/1000A/10000E'
DECLARE @test2 VARCHAR(100) = 'PRODUCT/100000A/PRODUCT/10U'
DECLARE @test3 VARCHAR(100) = 'PRODUCT/ITEM/1000U/PRODUCT/100000000E'
DECLARE @test4 VARCHAR(100) = 'PRODUCT/100000A/PRODUCT/423587U'

--Reverse the string to find '/U'  
----We want to do this to find the 'Starting position' for the SUBSTRING function
----Add 2 to get past the /U
SELECT REVERSE(@test1)
SELECT CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))+2

--Find the next '/' in the reversed string using the /U location as the starting location
----Have to add 1 to get past the length of '/'
SELECT CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@test1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))+1)

--Get the string between these two values
----Need the reversed string, the starting position, and the difference between the end and start(meaning length of the string to return) 
----Again, have to do a little adjustment to the numbers to remove the / and /U 
SELECT SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@test1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))+2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@test1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))+1) - CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))-2)

--Reverse the whole thing to get the final value
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@test1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1)) +2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@test1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))+1) - CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@test1))-2))


SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@test1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST1)) +2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@TEST1), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST1))+1) -CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST1))-2))
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@TEST2), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST2)) +2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@TEST2), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST2))+1) -CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST2))-2))
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@TEST3), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST3)) +2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@TEST3), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST3))+1) -CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST3))-2))
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@TEST4), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST4)) +2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@TEST4), CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST4))+1) -CHARINDEX('/U', REVERSE(@TEST4))-2))
```

Comment: Well - this can be - uhm - simplified ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with a *little little* less complication ;-)

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Products VARCHAR(100));  
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('PRODUCT/100U/PRODUCT/1000A/10000E')
,('PRODUCT/100000A/PRODUCT/10U')
,('PRODUCT/ITEM/1000U/PRODUCT/100000000E');
```

--the query

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Products
          ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(Products,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]u/%',Products + '/'))) AS CutEndReverse
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT Products
      ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(CutEndReverse,1,CHARINDEX('/',CutEndReverse)-1)) AS YourNumber
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT REPLACE(Products,'U','') AS Products
FROM
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Products
FROM
(
SELECT CAST( '<S>'+REPLACE(Products,'/','</S><S>')+'</S>'  AS XML ) AS Products
FROM @tbl
)AS A
CROSS APPLY Products.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)dt 
WHERE Products LIKE '%U'
```

Result

```
Products
100
10
1000
```

Comment: This relys on the assumption that there is no other item ending with an `U`. I don't know, but  I thought, that `PRDUCT` might be a place holder for a product's name (same with `ITEM`)... If one of them was ending on `U` this would fail.